# How to get the exact text value of a link which has a html label inside?

Tags: jquery, html

I need to get the exact text value of a nested html link element. I understand if you want to get the text value of this element

```
<a id="mylink" >Hello</a>
```

is just

```
$("#mylink").text();
```

but in this case I have

```
<a id="mylink" >Hello <label id="mylab" >Hi!...</label></a>
```

and I only need the inner text value which is **Hello** only. I don't need the value of the label. How do I do this in jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
$($("#mylink").contents()[0]).text(); // gives you the first text
$($("#mylink").contents()[1]).text(); //gives u the second text
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/f8edc4gw/)

The index in`contents()[0]` represents the text that should be returned, whereby `0` is the first, `1` is the second, `2` would be the third, etc...

Comment: Thanks...That is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `:has` selector to get the anchor element that has label in it. and getting the second part(i.e. getting text node in element) can be easily googled to get different solution:

```
$('a:has(label)').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType === 3; //Node.TEXT_NODE
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nzeq4h22/)**

Comment: In your fiddle you are returning both text values. I only need one which is "Hello". I don't need the text value inside the label

Comment: @timmack: that is what it does. have you checked the fiddle??

Comment: Do we really need to construct a function?Is there a simpler way not to use a function just like declaring a variable or a simple command. The reason why I dont need a function because I need that value for a query. I don't want to complicate things

Comment: the result returns string in fiddle you can use it as variable.

Comment: stored in variable data . check it . you can use anywhere on the page .

Comment: What do you mean this.nodeType === 3;? what does number 3 there represents.

Comment: @timmack: that ensure that only text nodes are selected. using approach like `contents()[0])` will break when position of text node is changed.

Comment: Let me test them including your function I think you've got the right message. I have a long text that is broken in position. Hold on for a moment.

Comment: @timmack: check this http://jsfiddle.net/tc4turma/. it shows how contents with indexing will throw wrong result

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Nope actually your function but it wont catch the return string value. You said that with this $($("#mylink").contents()[0]).text(); it will break when position of text is change but I tested it. It doesn't failed it it's still accurate in catching the exact value rather than using function. So I guess the best solution is still using $($("#mylink").contents()[0]).text();

Comment: have checked the fiddle when you swap text and label position?? do it still result hello?? no it will not. it will result hi instead

Comment: Ah ok so that's what you mean but I'm still having trouble on getting the string value using this  $('a:has(label)').contents().filter(function () {
            return this.nodeType === 3; //Node.TEXT_NODE
        }).text()

Comment: Ok I'll be there. Thanks for helping me

Comment: @timmack: what is the trouble. it returns string.

Comment: Let's talk in the chat session

Answer (score 1):

How about you clone the element, remove() the children and then get the text?

```
var div = $("#mylink").clone();
div.children().remove();
var output = div.text();
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/roboroads/bcj7z1rc/

Comment: Nice...This is just what I need. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just have this function

```
function getText(elm) {
    return $(elm)
        .clone()
        .children()
        .remove()
        .end()
        .text()
        .trim();
}
```

Pass the element and you'll get it's text without any child node values.

Comment: I don't need to return a function because I just want a simple declarative statement to use the value as query

Comment: I made it a function just to ensure reusability, but you can use it normally as well. This is comprehensive in the sense that it can remove any child value and trim the result.

Comment: Also, I see your selected answer still returns child value as well. I think, I might have misunderstood the answer then